# How does get list of Stage names values after select opportunity name

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Apex Class:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static list<Map<string,string>> getstagenamesByopportunityName(List<String> Names) 
    {
        list<Map<string,string>> ret=new list<Map<string,string>>();
        list<opportunity> opps=[select  Id, Name,Account.Name,OrderNumber__c,StageName,Amount  from opportunity where Name IN :Names];
        for(opportunity o:opps)
        {
            Map<string,string> mapstr1=new Map<string,string>();
            mapstr1.put(o.Name,o.StageName);
            ret.add(mapstr1);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Component:

```
<div class="slds-container--small slds-box slds-box--small slds-theme--shade slds-text-align--center">
                                    <div class="head slds-container--large">Opportunity Name</div> 


                                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.number}" var="wrap"  indexVar="idx" aura:id="mySelect2">
                                         <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(idx,2)}">

                                                <ui:inputSelect aura:id="select"  class="slds-select"  change="{!c.onchange1}" value="{!v.selectedValue1}">
                                            <!--<lightning:Select aura:id="mySelect1" value="{!v.selectedValue}" change="{!c.onchange}" >-->
                                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item1" indexVar="idx1" >

                                                 <option text="{!item1.label }" value="{!item1.name }" selected="{!item1.selected}"/>
                                                <ui:outputText value="{!item1.StageName}" /><br/>

                                                 </aura:iteration>
                                             </ui:inputSelect>  

                                            </aura:if>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                            </div>

    <div class="slds-container--small slds-box slds-box--small slds-theme--shade slds-text-align--center">
                                    <div class="head slds-container--large">Stgae Name</div> 


                                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.prds1}" var="wrap"  indexVar="idx" aura:id="mySelect">
                                         <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(idx,2)}">
                                              <ui:outputText value="{!wrap.StageName}" aura:id="reason"/><br/>
                                              </aura:if>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                            </div>
```

ComponentcontrollerJs:

```
onchange1:  function (component, event, helper) 
    {

        var selected = component.get("v.selectedValue1");
        var selectedVal = helper.filterOPPNAMES(selected);
        console.log("selected value:"+selectedVal);
        //var action = component.get("c.getopportunityByNames");
        var action = component.get("c.getstagenamesByopportunityName");
        action.setParam("Names", selectedVal);
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
        component.set("v.prds1", response.getReturnValue());
            console.log("prds1 values:"+component);
        } else{
        component.set("v.prds1",[]);
        }
            });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        console.log("prds1 values:"+action);
    },
```

Helper:

[image: Selected opportunity names does not getting into stagename]

```
filterOPPNAMES : function(selected)
    {
        console.log("filterOPPNAMES:"+selected);
        return this.getstagenamesFromList(selected.Name) ; 


    },

    getstagenamesFromList : function(list)
    {
        var ret = [];
        for (var i in list)  ///** opportunity names does not added to list**/
        {
        return push(list[i].Name);
        }
        return ret;
    },
```

Comment: You have to store id of the opportunity in some attribute and call the controller on select.

Comment: try to use change handler by aura

Comment: I am new to lightning concepts. can anybody help, How to write to use change handler  and customise  code.